# Place background image in middle of table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

Look at the image below

[image]

How do you center the image in the table collumn (`<td>`)? Padding don't space at the top only to the right and bottom

Here is the table html code

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="bedButton ward-A">A115:1</td>
<td class="bedButton ward-A">A116:1</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
.bedButton{
    padding:25px;
    width:250px;
    height:300px;
    background:url(../images/bedview/bed-background.png) no-repeat;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}
```

Comment: you mean align the text in the middle of a td?? text-align, and vertical-align center?

Comment: No I mean allign the Background image in the center of the <td> =)

Comment: oh you might wanna edit the question to clarify exactly what you are trying to do. background-position: center center; might do it

Comment: Please include the absolute URL to the background-image as we can't see it ..

Comment: Background.position did it, thank you :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To horizontally center the text, use:

```
td {
    text-align:center;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qmRLa/)**

Comment: How about the background image? background:url(../images/bedview/bed-background.png) no-repeat; ? =)

Comment: Set `50% 50%` on the position part of the background like `background: url('http://www.placekitten.com/250/300') no-repeat  50% 50%;`. See http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qmRLa/2/